# How do I find out the exact publication date/time of a press release (Reuters, PR Newswire)?

Tags: earnings, news

I'm interested in the impact of a press release on related stock prices. The reliability of the timestamp is also important to me.

Of course, an important point here is the realtime latency of a platform, i.e. how many (milli)seconds pass from the publication at the source until this message reaches its destination. This is **not the main aspect** I'm looking for, but rather: How [accurate and precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) are the timestamps (creation, modification, publication...) that are attached to a news message, e.g. a press release? Imagine using the data in a scientific publication, then the data points used in a graph should have error bars (better: a standard deviation) on the *t* axis.

Examples:

- https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/bps-head-crude-trading-wise-retire-sources-2022-08-02/ says 5:19 PM GMT+0 at the top. I received this via TradingView, which says the timestamp is 1659460510 which is equal to Aug 2 2022, 17:15:10 GMT+0. This is approx. 4 mins earlier, and also, the given precision is higher (seconds instead of minutes).
- https://seekingalpha.com/news/3864970-just-who-is-amtd-digital-and-why-have-its-shares-climbed-15000-since-mid-july says 1:45 PM ET. TradingView says 17:45:12 GMT+0, which works out - again, higher given precision.
- https://www.wsj.com/livecoverage/stock-market-news-today-08-02-2022/card/pinterest-shares-surge-premarket-on-elliott-stake-qODDsiw8TtbMHaCMcLwH says 7:18 AM. I got this via IBKR and it says 7:18:00, so it checks out.
- https://seekingalpha.com/news/3864533-pinterest-surges-20-as-elliott-moves-in-susquehanna-upgrades-citing-new-catalysts says 7:21 AM ET. IBKR says 7:21:07.
- https://www.wsj.com/articles/moderna-revenue-rises-on-strong-demand-for-covid-19-vaccine-11659527439?siteid=yhoof2 says 9:30 AM ET. Yahoo Finance also shows this https://finance.yahoo.com/m/e24b0950-99ec-379e-a8e7-814f5df7e7dd/moderna-profit-falls-amid.html and displays the same time.
- https://www.accesswire.com/710670/Moderna-Reports-Second-Quarter-2022-Financial-Results-and-Provides-Business-Updates is the original press release and says 7 AM (ET, as far as I can tell). In IBKR, I see that **Dow Jones Global News** immediately (=07:00:00) republished Net, Rev and EPS as three separate "headlines" as well as the full balance sheets and the original press release. Then, **Reuters** publishes the original press release at 07:00:13 (that is: thirteen seconds later). **DJ Global News** then publishes additional "headline style" information at 07:01:00 and 07:02:00. **Benzinga** follows at 07:02:36 which reads as an automatically generated piece, **StreetInsider.com** does the same thing at 07:02:50. **Benzinga** says "ah wait, there is also a buyback announcement" at 07:02:51 and "also, advance purchase agreements where reiterated" at 07:03:19. **SeekingAlpha** at 07:08:30.

Can anyone explain to me how this works? E.g.

- Is there a standardized timestamp format for press releases (at least within an agency)?
- Are there typical latencies for premium platforms and "normal" brokers (Bloomberg Terminal vs. IBKR/Yahoo Finance)?
- Is the displayed date usually the creation date or the modified date or does anyone even care?

Comment: A lot of people care, so much that it's a huge business - BBG sells so called [event driven feeds](https://www.bloomberg.com/company/stories/tackling-enterprise-customers-need-speed-real-time-meets-mandate/), as do most competitors. Standard for API solution will be UTC time stamps. I cannot comment on what provider will be fastest because it's not my area of expertise but generally this will cost a lot of money because information advantages are "priceless", although you do not need real time, which should be cheaper. If you have access to Bloomberg, you can ask them on their systems detail.

Comment: You should usually find NIST and UTC is used throughout and they are essentially the same time. NIST is the “US version” of the UTC time standard and they synch to each other. As an end user with a GUI (Reuters or BBG terminal for example) you will see the time of your interface's settings but underneath it will be synced to UTC almost surely.

Comment: Thank you for those important points. I was referring to an other aspect, separate from the "realtime" aspect (also edited the question to make this more clear): The [precision and accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision). For comparison: I can look up the [Solar Eclipse 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_August_11,_1999) and Ref. 7 there gives me time of the "Greatest Eclipse" down to 100 ms. So if I were to analyze the impact of solar eclipses on the financial market, this is good precision and has nothing to do with realtime.

Comment: Regarding the "standardized timestamp": UTC/NIST is an important aspect, but there are others. E.g. TradingView uses Unix Timestamps down to the second, but many websites (see above) only give minutes. Additionally, there might be some offset values, hypothetically: Bloomberg Terminal could have an additional latency of 3s in Germany compared to Chicago and this could show in historical data.

Comment: The only way to get accurate timestamps without paying is to record them yourself in realtime, this isn't an easy problem to solve. You won't get them from the website itself, yeah it will say "published 7:00pm" but it could have been pushed live several ms before or after 7:00pm.

Comment: Sadly, recording on my own doesn't directly lead to reliable accuracy. Also, I'm more interested in the timestamp that the press agency (or any relay, like the IBKR News Feed) itself assigns to their own messages. 
The reason is: If all parties use synchronized time, all effects will happen *after* this initial action. I agree that it might be possible that information is published slightly before a planned release time to compensate for statistical "tardiness" of the website.

Comment: To circle back to your 7:00pm example: Yes, they could say that. But imagine they'd add a timestamp "published 7:00:00 GMT+0" but they actually published it at 7:23:49 GMT+0. This would be somehow fine if they'd write "published 7 am GMT+0", but with given seconds, it wouldn't be. To use the above example - why would DJ Global News be 13s faster than Reuters (with a timestamp created by them or IBKR, I don't know that but this would actually be one of the bigger points of this issue)?

Comment: I would not trust TradingView. It is very unlikely that the actual source of the news will be slower (your first link is a Reuters article, written by a Reuters journalist and published on Reuters). I know you do not care about real time, but the only way News providers will care about exact time stamps is if they record it accurately themselves. As you figured out yourself, the time stamps of various agencies depends on the time they receive / retrieve it, and store it on their system.

Comment: Bloomberg will not have a latency in your use case. The time stamp is what is recorded on Bloomberg's side - in real time applications, proximity to the server matters, but it will still read the same timestamp, no whether where you are. Unix Epoch is based on UTC under the hood as well, as confirmed by [Tradingviews]https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/concepts/Time.html own documentation. Bottom line is that you will need to pay for a service that will be reliable and accurate. None will always be quicker than the other, but Reuters and Bloomberg will be very close to the top

Comment: Thank you for all the information! If you want, you can put together an answer around the "News providers will care about exact time stamps is if they record it" point and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people care:

- for real time trading purposes
- for backtesting purposes where a correct point in time is crucial

As an end user with a GUI (Reuters or BBG terminal for example) you will see the time of your interface's settings but under the hood it will be synced to UTC almost surely. For example, Tradingviews Unix Epoch is also based on UTC as well, which is confirmed by [Tradingviews](https://tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/concepts/Time.html)  documentation. Bottom line, the time will be synced to UTC or NIST, with the latter being the “US version” of the UTC time standard and they synch to each other.

Also regulators base their clocks of UTC. For example, the Markets in Financial Instruments Directive II ([MiFID II](https://fsmlabs.com/mifid-ii-ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-clock-sync/)) in Europe and the Consolidated Audit Trail (CAT) in the USA require server clocks synchronisation to be within 100 microseconds of UTC.

I believe Yahoo and the like store the timestamp when they receive or scrape the news headline. It is not their business to provide fast and reliable news. It is highly unlikely that Tradingview will beat Reuters in a Reuters article, written by a Reuters journalist and published on Reuters.

The only way News providers will care about exact time stamps is if they record it accurately themselves and can earn money with this business model. Data providers like Bloomberg and Reuters created a huge business out of the demand for this. For example, Bloomberg sells so called [Even Driven Feeds](https://www.bloomberg.com/company/stories/tackling-enterprise-customers-need-speed-real-time-meets-mandate/). You will not need this feed because you do not need real time, but you will need a provider that cares about accuracy.

I recommend you reach out to the major providers and ask what they can offer. To figure out the impact on financial markets also requires you to get accurate market data. Based on your request at least down to the second. That in itself will be quite difficult to obtain, especially if you need a bit of history as well.

To see the accuracy of release data, if you have access to Bloomberg, you can look at `ECO`, for economic data calendar which shows the time of scheduled releases. You can backdate this and compare with the news articles that come in. When you see BFW as the source - it will be a direct automated report once retrieved, with the time stamp in seconds. `ECMI` uses these time stamps and computes the reaction of selected securities to surprises.